# Большая, но редкая транзакция или маленькая, но частая?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим, нужно вставить некоторое число записей в транзакции в несколько таблиц.

Так вот, встал вопрос, лучше делать вставку маленькими порциями, но часто (например, по 100 записей) или вставлять большим числом записей, но реже(например, 10 000).

Читал, что лучше, что бы транзакция быстрее заканчивалась, но так же читал, что транзакция- это дорогая операция.

Т.е 2 утверждения, которые противоречат друг другу.

Допустим, из этих таблиц происходит постоянные чтение данных какими-то прикладными ПО. При каком подходе, вставки для конечного пользователя будут вызывать меньший дискомфорт(я подозреваю, что больших и нечастых)

Comment: У большой транзакции накладные расходы меньше. А у маленькой транзакции время задержки ожидания других пользователей меньше. Поэтому, чтобы время обслуживания было оптимально, нужно динамически менять размер транзакции в зависимости от нагрузки на базу данных. При маленькой нагрузке на базу данных нужно увеличивать размер транзакции, а при большой нагрузке на базу  данных нужно уменьшать размер транзакции.

Comment: Если у вас в основе OLTP система (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLTP) то делайте короткие транзакции, либо переносите массовые действия на нерабочие часы (при их наличии). Да, короткие транзакции заметно дороже, за единицу времени вы вставите гораздо меньше данных, но это цена уменьшения времени отклика для остальных пользователей.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Краткий и точный ответ на данный вопрос, к сожалению, невозможен. Чтобы понимать плюсы и минусы различного размера транзакций, нужно глубоко погружаться в особенности работы database engine и рассматривать разные особенности - тип таблицы (с кластерным индексом или без), тип вставки (в конец таблицы или в случайные страницы), тип изоляции транзакций, который используется в текущий момент.

Я попытаюсь объяснить вкратце, в меру своего понимания. Учтите, что мой ответ будет наверняка неточным в некоторых моментах и не учитывать определенные особенности.

Итак, что происходит в транзакции, которая вставляет данные:

1. На таблицу, в которую происходит вставка, накладывается блокировка на изменение схемы (так, чтобы никто не мог изменить определение таблицы в момент вставки).
2. На строки, в которые будет происходить запись, накладывается блокировка на обновление - такая блокировка не позволит читать такие строки в другой транзакции при определенных уровнях изоляции транзакций, например, READ COMMITTED, до тех пор, пока ваша транзакция не завершится. При массивной вставке может произойти эскалация блокировок, и, например, вместо строк будут блокироваться страницы или (в некоторых случаях) вся таблица целиком
3. Записи, добавляемые в таблицы, также пишутся в журнал транзакций, при этом, пока транзакция не завершена, такие записи из журнала не могут быть удалены.
4. При завершении транзакции запись в журнале помечается завершенной, и может быть удалена сразу при SIMPLE-модели восстановления или после создания резервной копии журнала при FULL или BULK-logged модели.
5. Снимаются блокировки, наложенные транзакцией

Как следствие, в плюсах короткой транзакции - краткое время блокировки записей таблицы, ваши пользователи, скорее всего, не заметят задержек в работе, в минусах - высокие относительные накладные расходы на создание и завершение транзакции.

В плюсах длинной транзакции - низкие относительные накладные расходы на создание и завершение транзакции, в минусах - рост ожидания доступа к данным, рост журнала транзакций, что при очень больших транзакциях может стать проблемой.

Рост ожидания доступа к данным можно "лечить" выбором другого уровня изоляции транзакций - например, READ UNCOMMITED (но он имеет свои отрицательные последствия в виде грязного чтения, например), или READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT (повышает нагрузку на tempdb).